# bokeh server, generate session-id with secret key

Tags: server, tornado, bokeh

We are trying to embed dashboards produced with bokeh-server inside our internal web portal, using iframes. Bokeh server is cloud hosted and our web portal is accessible from outside.
Atm, we are struggling to secure bokeh server and make it available through web portal. I believe, we need to generate session-id from our web portal, but we have limited control over it.

Is there a way to pass secret key to bokeh-server and let it generate session itself? So that we can embed iframe in web portal with a like, such as: http://bokeh-prod.acke.com/movies?bokeh-secret=Sup3rSec5etK3y

Or is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

hope you have solved the issue now, but if not, I found the way to do it: Bokeh server checks session IDs if you run it with `bokeh serve app.py --session-ids=external-signed`. You can then use the function `bokeh.util.session_id.generate_session_id` in your web portal application in order to generate a valid session ID.

Both bokeh server and the web application need to have environment variables BOKEH_SECRET_KEY='' (you can generate a secret key using `bokeh secret`) and BOKEH_SIGN_SESSIONS=true.

I will go into more detail about the process if you still have a need.

Comment: Thanks. Knowing the web app needed to have `BOKEH_SIGN_SESSIONS=true` was the missing link for me.